# Регулярное выражение js. Разбить строку на массив по правильному содержанию

Tags: match

К примеру у меня есть строка:

```
'
    []dfglkergrg[]dfgr[/]dfgrg[]rgdfg[/][/]
    []dfglkergrg[]dfgr[/]dfgrg[/]
    []dfglkergrg dfgrg[/]
'
```

Возможно ли с помощью регулярного выражения
разбить эту строку на такой массив?

```
[
 [0]: '[]dfglkergrg[]dfgr[/]dfgrg[]rgdfg[/][/]',
 [1]: '[]dfglkergrg[]dfgr[/]dfgrg[/]',
 [2]: '[]dfglkergrg dfgrg[/]'
]
```

Если да, то можете написать **regexp** или подсказать как лучше или ссылку..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем тут, собственно, регулярное выражение?

```
`
    []dfglkergrg[]dfgr[/]dfgrg[]rgdfg[/][/]
    []dfglkergrg[]dfgr[/]dfgrg[/]
    []dfglkergrg dfgrg[/]
`.split('\n').map((s)=>s.trim()).filter((s)=>s.length !== 0) // ["[]dfglkergrg[]dfgr[/]dfgrg[]rgdfg[/][/]", "[]dfglkergrg[]dfgr[/]dfgrg[/]", "[]dfglkergrg dfgrg[/]"]
```

Не, ну можно и регуляркой...

```
[...`
    []dfglkergrg[]dfgr[/]dfgrg[]rgdfg[/][/]
    []dfglkergrg[]dfgr[/]dfgrg[/]
    []dfglkergrg dfgrg[/]
`.matchAll(/[^\n]+[\n|\S]/g)]
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Быстрота..

Comment: Большое спасибо!.

Comment: @Arthur Если ответ помог, пометьте как верный